# Typing code with minted and Greek: "! Package polyglossia Error: The current roman font does not contain the Greek"

Tags: minted, polyglossia

I have made my first tex text in order to test how to use it on my essays:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass[a4paper,draft]{article} 
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[Greek,Latin]{ucharclasses}
% Language declaration
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\setTransitionsForGreek{\selectlanguage{greek}}{\selectlanguage{english}}

% Fonts
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Kerning=On,Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}


\title{My first document}
\date{2018-03-17}
\author{Dimitrios Desyllas}

\begin{document}
 \maketitle
 \newpage

 \section{Πρώτο κεφάλαιο}
    Καλημέρα Greece. This is an English paragraph
    \subsection{Υποκεφάλαιο 1}
    Στην Ελλάδα έχει ήλιο
    \subsubsection{Υποκεφάλαιο }
    Που καίει πολύ
    \subsubsection{Υπουπόκεφάλαιο 1.1}
    Πάρα πολύ
    \subsection{Υποκεφάλαιο 2}
    Στην Ελλάδα έχει θάλλασα
 \section{Δεύτερο κεφάλαιο}
 Όλα πάνε ρόδινα

\begin{english}
\begin{minted}{java}
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Hello extends JApplet {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello, world!", 65, 95);
    }    
}
\end{minted}
\end{english}

\end{document}
```

But on the section:

```
\begin{english}
\begin{minted}{java}
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Hello extends JApplet {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello, world!", 65, 95);
    }    
}
\end{minted}
\end{english}
```

I get the following error:

```
! Package polyglossia Error: The current roman font does not contain the Greek
```

How I can solve it?

Comment: You might try to use Libertinus Serif instead of Linux Libertine O, for one. Then also, as far as I can see, you are trying to set the Greek sans font to a roman font. I don't know if this might confuse TeX. If you are not going to switch to the newer Libertinus, then at least try using Linux Libertine Sans instead of the `O` version. That might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is unfortunately misleading, as it refers to the “roman font” rather than the mono font.

Add a declaration for `\greekfonttt` choosing a font that supports Greek.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft]{article} 
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[Greek,Latin]{ucharclasses}
% Language declaration
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\setTransitionsForGreek{\selectlanguage{greek}}{\selectlanguage{english}}

% Fonts
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Kerning=On,Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}


\title{My first document}
\date{2018-03-17}
\author{Dimitrios Desyllas}

\begin{document}
 \maketitle
 \newpage

 \section{Πρώτο κεφάλαιο}
    Καλημέρα Greece. This is an English paragraph
    \subsection{Υποκεφάλαιο 1}
    Στην Ελλάδα έχει ήλιο
    \subsubsection{Υποκεφάλαιο }
    Που καίει πολύ
    \subsubsection{Υπουπόκεφάλαιο 1.1}
    Πάρα πολύ
    \subsection{Υποκεφάλαιο 2}
    Στην Ελλάδα έχει θάλασσα
 \section{Δεύτερο κεφάλαιο}
 Όλα πάνε ρόδινα

\begin{english}
\begin{minted}{java}
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Hello extends JApplet {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello, world!", 65, 95);
    }    
}
\end{minted}
\end{english}

\end{document}
```

I removed the useless bits, particularly the loading of `xltxtra` and the confusing font setting.

[image]

Comment: θάλασσα (one lambda two sigmas)…

Comment: @yannis Yes, of course. I just copied the OP's text and my knowledge of Greek doesn't go far beyond the alphabet.